# Equivalent matlab command on aforge library

Tags: c#, matlab, aforge, equivalent

I want to find equivalent matlab command in aforge library.

```
image = imread('image path');
image = imopen(image,strel('line',2);
```

What equivalent on the `Aforge` libray ?

Answer (score 0):

A little google-fu "aforge opening" led me to this:

http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/89cfb62e-3307-0f8c-9c59-16b588f32807.htm

This:

http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/1110f43b-7741-8df9-69b8-19d4dd2b795f.htm

Seems to specify how to get the right structuring element.